# html- placing image perfectly inside div

Tags: html, css

I want an image to perfectly fit into a div

The CSS part is:

```
            #demo1 ul li { 
            width: 12.5%;
            }   

            .gPop-gallery {
            display: block;
            margin-top: -1%;
            margin-left: 8%;
            }

            .gPop-gallery ul {
            width: 98%;
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-block;
            padding-left: 15px;
            }

            .gPop-gallery ul:first-child li {
            margin-top: 1%; 
            }

            .gPop-gallery ul li {
            float: left; 
            width: 100%;
            border-radius: 3px;
            margin-top: -1.5%;
            margin-right: 1%;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            }

            .gPop-gallery ul li div img {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid red;
            }
```

The html part is:

```
<div class="gPop-gallery" id="demo1">

            <ul>                  
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="0" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="1" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="2" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="3" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="4" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="5" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="6" src=""></div></li>
            </ul> 
            <ul>                  
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="7" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="8" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="9" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="10" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="11" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="12" src=""></div></li>
                <li><div style="position: relative;"><img class="imgs" id="13" src=""></div></li>
            </ul> 

        </div>
```

The output is:

[image]

The image width is exceeding div's width.

Currently I've just set li's background color as white, but even after I give src to img tag, the problem remains...

Answer (score 3):

You use 1px border for your images...

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

**should go for your images.** or in any case to the element **that has the border.**

---

Anyhow, I would use this CSS: **[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/dalot/7/edit)**

```
.gPop-gallery ul {
    background:#444;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0%;
}
.gPop-gallery ul li {
    float: left; 
    width: 12.2%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 1%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

.gPop-gallery ul li div img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Isn't working when I put the above code in .gPop-gallery ul li div img

Comment: there is still problem with some of images

Comment: @Engineer: Just noticed that even after the mentioned setting, at lower resolutions some images go out of the box (like Super Hornet has mentioned). It might be better in that case to reduce width to 99%.

Comment: @Super@engeneer I cannot see that issue in firefox even after resizeing on any size. Can you try this modified demo? http://jsbin.com/dalot/3/edit

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `box-sizing` to the images also.

```
.gPop-gallery ul li div img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;    
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8PK2W/)

**Explanation:** The reason is because as per `width` setting, the image would take 100% and it still has an extra border to fit. Generally `box-sizing` is `padding-box` and the `border` is not a part of the box width. When using `border-box` the border size also becomes a part of the 100% width.

Comment: What could be an alternative way to page center  .gPop-gallery ?

Comment: i dont want the margin-left, i want to page center gPop-gallery

Comment: Ok, how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8PK2W/2/)? Note: I have removed some of the older comments as it is getting a bit too lengthy.

Comment: is not centering gPop-gallery

Comment: In that fiddle it seems to be centering correctly mate. Can you create a sample fiddle with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Define margins, linewidths as pixels (e.g. 1px) instead of percentage.
The pixel linewidth should always take fixed number of pixels, where percentages may vary depending on window size and even placement.

Size for scaling of images would indeed typically be a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the `.gPop-gallery` class with `margin-left: 8%` causes the problem
but if you use `px` instead of percent it could work better.

Comment: an 8% margin can do no harm to any element on your page.

Comment: I just tested it does!

Comment: margin-left was causing the problem. So now how to align the ul in the middle of the page

Comment: Makes no sense to me. 8% margin on a DIV element... c'mon.

Comment: I was using margin-left to have the ul in near centre of the page, So without that how could i center the ul in some alternative way?

Comment: @Engineer `near-center` question cannot give you any desired specific answer. Please be concise. What you actually need? A page-centered UL with thumbnails inside LI elements?

Comment: by margin-left there is no enough space for children!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, i want A page-centered UL with thumbnails inside LI elements

Comment: you should use `margin: 0 auto;` instead @Engineer

Comment: you should set `margin: 0 auto;` on `body` not `.gPop-Gallery`

Answer (score 0):

`width:100%` is not working here, because actual size of image becomes 100% + 2px of border.(1px for left border and 1px for right border).

You can solve this by using `calc()`.

Change `width:100%` to `width:calc(100% - 2px)`.

Please note, this does not work with all browsers.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9BWJ/) here.